# Convert hex Ascii representation in a bytes object to Ascii string using Python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, type-conversion, byte

I want to convert a variable containing a `bytes` object of Ascii data to a string.
Ex:

```
a=bytearray(b'31303031')
```

I want to convert it to:

```
'1001'
```

How to do this in Python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert each pair to integer from base 16, get the appropriate character, and concatenate:

```
''.join(chr(int(a[i:i+2], 16)) for i in range(0,len(a),2))
```

Of course, you do not really have a `bytes` object of hexadecimals, but a string. So, get back the string, make a real hexadecimal `bytes` object, and decode that is another option:

```
bytes.fromhex(a.decode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
```